# How to use Android in hungarian?

Tags: android

I have checked the regional settings in my emulator and I can't yet choose Hungarian.
I am wondering how can I make my application to work in hungarian? How do I set what language to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android does not officially support Hungarian at this time, so the emulator does not have Hungarian strings. You can see the list of supported languages on each SDK's [release notes page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.1.html).

Comment: ow can I make my application to work in hungarian? How do I maintan sync of string.xml between default and -hu? And how do I tell app to change locale?

Comment: "How can I make my application to work in hungarian?" AFAIK, there is no way to tell an Android device that it is Hungarian, so `-hu` resource sets would never be used. So, instead of standard Android string resources, you will need to maintain your own string table and load your messages from there. Plus, you will need to allow the user to choose Hungarian from some settings activity inside of your own app, since they cannot choose Hungarian for the device as a whole. I don't know of anything easier. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer:

Android supports Hungarian out of the box, took me some time to figure out it's called "`Magyar`" in the Languages list, and it properly uses all values contained in `values-hu`